What is the difference between normative and prescriptive statements?
Are they just synonyms?
Thanks.

Norms are constraints on permissible actions, prescriptions are instructions to perform those actions. It is the same difference as between specifying what a computer program should do and producing a program that does it, see Bahnik et al.:"These two types of judgments differ in significant ways – while normative judgments are value judgments and are likely to be based solely on the morality of the action, prescriptive judgments require additional inference from values to a recommendation of an action."

DEscribe vs PREscribe: to say what is vs to say what to do. Time.  Values would just add post-hoc rationalizations, as always. (and 'scribe' means write, but, anyway...)

The Wikipedia article on normativity can answer your question. "Normative" and "prescriptive" are in most contexts synonyms that describe what ought to be done. But in some contexts, "normative" refers instead to what is normally or conventionally done.

To be honest, I asked this question because multiple different websites gave completely different answers.
I think the best answer is :
Normative statements are statements that have a value judgment.
Prescriptive statements are statements that say what you should do (implicitly having a value judgment, thus rendering it as a subset of normative statements).
So there are normative statements that are not prescriptive (e.g. "Honesty is good").
But all prescriptive statements are normative statements ("You should not lie.")

Also, I have to ask. Can a statement be both descriptive and normative. E.g. "Honesty is good". Is that only normative, or can it be descriptive as its almost kind of described as a state of affair. Idk tho
